# How to disable list component from changing colour when tapped on in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

I would like to be able to disable an item in the list component from changing colour when tapped on in Sencha touch. Is there a way to do this? I browsed through the api documentation of the list component but couldn't see a configuration option that allowed this to be changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting the `selectedCls` to an empty string in the List's config.

Comment: also do : `pressedCls:''`  this will give a fine tune.

Answer (score 0):

listen the 'select' event on list component and return false